# How to create a comma delimited string from distinct list of values using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of values:

```
myCars
```

with values:

```
Ford
Ford
VW
Renault
Jeep
Jeep
```

which is referenced via:

```
myCars.Makers
```

I wish to create a **distinct comma delimited string** from this such that I get:

```
Ford,VW,Renault,Jeep
```

I am guessing that I need to run a distinct clause on myCars, but then am unsure about how to convert to comma delimited string as above.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string.Join(",", myCars.Makers.Distinct());
```

Comment: That has to be one of the quickest replies. Thanks.